# Goodness-of-fit test without analytical PDF and CDF

Tags: distributions, modeling, density-function, goodness-of-fit, moment-generating-function

I have closed form moment-generating function and characteristic function of a distribution, which describes waiting time of a continuous univariate random process.  However, I cannot  analytically invert the characteristic function to get PDF.

Now, I have run simulations of the original process in order to verify that my model adequately describes the process. Because data in this case are simulated, I exactly know model parameters.  Therefore, I am not interested in parameter estimation for now.

By eyeballing histogram of simulated data and numerically computed PDF, my model seems to fit the data very well.  However, I want to say something more concrete and quantitative.  Is there any goodness-of-fit test with arbitrary distribution, whose PDF and CDF are not analytically available?
If not, what other approaches can I take?

Comment: What's the matter with numerically inverting the cf?

Comment: @whuber thank you for the comment.  I tried to use Mathematica to invert the cf.  However, it had a problem in integration under some parameter combinations.  I then switched to FFT-based approximation, which did not suffer the same problem.  However, the latter approach did not give densities at dense enough points.  Probably, can I try interpolation to fill the gaps?

Comment: For a GoF test you usually don't need the PDF: you only need the CDF at a fairly dispersed set of points.  That might be more reliably obtained than the PDF.